# Send no more than 1000 emails per hour Laravel Mail Queue

Tags: php, email, laravel, queue

How can I send no more than 1000 emails per hour on Laravel with Mail and Queue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use queue driver/server (e.g. beanstalkd), use Mail::queue() instead of Mail::send() and then run a cron job "php artisan queue:work"

Comment: You can read about it here: http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-queue-drivers

Comment: @MichailStrokin I'm already using the Database driver, with the Mail::queue, but I want to know how can I set a limit per hour of how much jobs the queue runs.

Comment: there's no magic methods for doing that AFAIK, probably easiest way to do that is to create a job which sends the messages, then fetch the number of processed jobs in last hour inside that job, and then 'release' the job if it's more than 1000 (using something like $this->release(10);)

Comment: @MichailStrokin thanks, I'll do that!

Comment: Maybe there is some way to use `Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin` (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783301/470749) within `SendQueuedMailable`?